# System.NotSupportedException in Entity Framework (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 project with Entity Framework. I have people (`Pajtas` class) which are in groups (every group has a unique number). The users can edit the people's information but only if the user has permission to the group in which the person is.

Every user has an `IfiAdatlap` object and the `IfiAdatlap` object has the permissions for the numbered groups. So I have a simple permisison class:

```
        public class CsoportHozzaferes
        {
            [Required]
            [Key]
            [Column(Order = 1)]
            public int Csoport { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Key]
            [Column(Order = 2)]
            public virtual IfiAdatlap IfiAdatlap { get; set; }
        }
```

In my controller I have a function to check that the current user's `IfiAdatlap` object has permission to the group in which the person is whose information the user would like to edit. First of all I get the current user's `ApplicationUser` object (`user`), than I try to get the list of groups (`csoportok`) for which the user has permission to be able to check that the person's group number (`pajtas.Csoport`) is in this list or not.

```
private void PajtasHozzaferesCheck(Pajtas pajtas)
        {
            var userName = User.Identity.Name;
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
            var csoportok = db.CsoportHozzaferesek.Where(h => h.IfiAdatlap != null && h.IfiAdatlap == user.Adatlap).Select(csh => csh.Csoport).ToList();
            if (!(pajtas.Csoport != null && csoportok.Contains((int)pajtas.Csoport)))
            {
                var tanfolyamok = db.TanfolyamHozzaferesek.Where(h => h.IfiAdatlap != null && h.IfiAdatlap == user.Adatlap).Select(tfh => tfh.Tanfolyam).ToList();
                var tfosztalyok = db.TanfolyamHozzaferesek.Where(h => h.IfiAdatlap != null && h.IfiAdatlap == user.Adatlap).Select(tfh => tfh.Osztaly).ToList();
                if (!(pajtas.TanfolyamOsztaly != null && pajtas.TanfolyamSorszam != null && tanfolyamok.Contains((int)pajtas.TanfolyamSorszam) && tfosztalyok.Contains((TanfolyamOsztaly)pajtas.TanfolyamOsztaly) && tanfolyamok.IndexOf((int)pajtas.TanfolyamSorszam) == tfosztalyok.IndexOf((TanfolyamOsztaly)pajtas.TanfolyamOsztaly)))
                {
                    var tanfvez = db.TanfolyamvezetesHozzaferesek.Where(h => h.IfiAdatlap != null && h.IfiAdatlap == user.Adatlap).Select(tfvh => tfvh.Tanfolyam).ToList();
                    if (!(pajtas.TanfolyamSorszam != null && tanfvez.Contains((int)pajtas.TanfolyamSorszam)))
                    {
                        if (!(User.IsInRole("Nevelo") || User.IsInRole("Admin")))
                        {
                            //nincs jogosultság
                            throw new HttpException((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Hozzáférés megtagadva");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But I get an exception at line `var csoportok = ...`:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'Ifi.Models.Adatlap'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume `Adaplap` is an entity.Change where condition using id instead comparing instances,eg:

```
.Where(h => h.IfiAdatlap != null && h.IfiAdatlap.Id == user.Adatlap.Id)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `h.IfiAdatlap == user.Adatlap`. Because this is a complex type, it won't be accepted, as EF does not know how to do the comparison. You need to compare the ids, something like `h.IfiAdatlap.Id == user.Adatlap.Id`.